# How to render an image with effect faster with UIKit

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I'm making an iOS app which there's a process to switch a lot of pictures with several UIImageViews (a loop to set image property of a UIImageView with a bunch of images). And sometimes some of the images needs some graphic effect, say multiplication.

The easiest way is to use a CIFilter to do this thing but the problem is that CALayer on iOS doesn't support "filters" property, so you need to apply the effect to the images before you set "image" property. But this is really too slow when you refresh the screen very frequently.

So next I tried to use Core Graphics directly to do the multiplication with UIGraphics context and kCGBlendModeMultiply. This is really much faster than using a CIFilter, but since you have to apply the multiplication before rendering the image, you can still feel the program runs slower while trying to render images with multiplication effect than rendering normal images.

My guess is that the fundamental problem of these 2 approaches is that you have to process the effect to the images with GPU, and then get the result image with CPU, then finally render the result image with GPU, which means the data transfer between CPU and GPU wasted a lot of time, so I then tried to change the super class from UIImageView to UIView and implement the CGGraphics context code to drawRect method, then when I set the "image" property I call setNeedsDisplay method in didSet. But this doesn't work so well... actually every time it calls setNeedsDisplay the program becomes much more slow that even slower than using a CIFilter, probably because there are several views displaying.

I guess that probably I can fix this problem with OpenGL but I'm wondering if I can solve this problem with UIKit only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you have to make the same changes to different images. So time of initial initialization is not critical for you but each image should be processed as soon as possible. First of all it is **critical** to generate new images in a background queue/thread.
There are two good ways to quickly process/generate images:

1. Use CIFilter from CoreImage
2. Use GPUImage library

If you used CoreImage check that you use CIFilter and CIContext properly. CIContext creation takes quite a lot of time but it could be **SHARED** between different CIFilters and images - so you should create CIContext only once! CIFilter could also be **SHARED** between different images, but since it is not thread safe you should have a separate CIFilter for each thread.

In my code I have the following:

```
+ (UIImage*)roundShadowImageForImage:(UIImage*)image {
    static CIFilter *_filter;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
    {
        NSLog(@"CIContext and CIFilter generating...");
        _context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:@{ kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: @NO,
                                                    kCIContextWorkingColorSpace : [NSNull null] }];

        CIImage *roundShadowImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[[self class] roundShadowImage].CGImage];
        CIImage *maskImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[[self class] roundWhiteImage].CGImage];

        _filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBlendWithAlphaMask" 
                             keysAndValues:
                   kCIInputBackgroundImageKey, roundShadowImage,
                   kCIInputMaskImageKey, maskImage, nil];
        NSLog(@"CIContext and CIFilter are generated");
    });

    if (image == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    NSAssert(_filter, @"Error: CIFilter for cover images is not generated");

    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width * image.scale, image.size.height * image.scale);

    // CIContext and CIImage objects are immutable, which means each can be shared safely among threads
    CIFilter *filterForThread = [_filter copy]; // CIFilter could not be shared between different threads.

    CGAffineTransform imageTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, coverSize)) {
        NSLog(@"Cover image. Resizing image %@ to required size %@", NSStringFromCGSize(imageSize), NSStringFromCGSize(coverSize));
        CGFloat scaleFactor = MAX(coverSide / imageSize.width, coverSide / imageSize.height);
        imageTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    }
    imageTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(imageTransform, extraBorder, extraBorder);

    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
    ciImage = [ciImage imageByApplyingTransform:imageTransform];

    if (image.hasAlpha) {
        CIImage *ciWhiteImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[self whiteImage].CGImage];
        CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISourceOverCompositing"
                                      keysAndValues:
                            kCIInputBackgroundImageKey, ciWhiteImage,
                            kCIInputImageKey, ciImage, nil];
        [filterForThread setValue:filter.outputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    }
    else
    {
        [filterForThread setValue:ciImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    }

    CIImage *outputCIImage = [filterForThread outputImage];
    CGImageRef cgimg = [_context createCGImage:outputCIImage fromRect:[outputCIImage extent]];
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return newImage;
}
```

If you are still not satisfied with the speed try [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) It is a very good library, it is also very fast because it uses OpenGL for image generation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But since the process of "setValue: forKey:" takes a lot of time, unfortunately the cost of producing 1 filtered image with CIFilter is more than doing with Core Graphics. And those images with filters are not the same images so I have to do "setValue: forKey" every time that is pulling the speed down. But thanks for your suggestion of GPUImage, I'll try it later.

Comment: @lovee Comparing to image processing (Core Graphics, CIFilter, GPUImage...) method "setValue: forKey:" takes nothing.

Comment: @lovee CIFilter/CIContext initialisation takes some time but then processing of each image is very quick. You will have the same in GPUImage - shader initialisation takes a while but then for each image it works very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and sorry for misunderstood your code. I checked the processing time for each step and I thought the `setValue: forKey:` method took a lot of time but it doesn't take as much as I thought. And also by limiting the number of filter objects to 1 and reuse it for all images it became faster than before. But unfortunately it's still not fast enough... Anyway really thank you for your reply.